# ANdroid Studio >> GetCount()

Tags: java, android

I have a simple question, which will help me to understand a lot ( I hope!)

Well, I have this code:

```
// Getting contacts Count
    public int getContactsCount() {

    helper = new DBHelper(CheckTable.this);
    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getReadableDatabase();

    String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + Market.TABLE;

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    cursor.close();

    // return count
    return cursor.getCount();
}
```

How may I display this number?!

I thank you in advance...

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by display the number?

Comment: Sure! I have a button that brings me, once clicked, to a new activity. There, its is written: Nbr of Players: 7, which corresponds to the number of entries in the db, in the table players. Am I clear? Thanks if you can help me because I haven't yet succeeded :( I bought a book about Android, and I did the tutorial at official website more than 5 times. Any help would be greatly appreciated... Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This method is going to `return` you an `int`. Hence you have to declare it in your class. Assuming that you want to display this number in the same class you can simply follow this:

```
   public class Example{

  // Getting contacts Count
    public int getContactsCount() {

    helper = new DBHelper(CheckTable.this);
    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getReadableDatabase();

    String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + Market.TABLE;

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    cursor.close();

    // return count
    return cursor.getCount();
}


 public static void main(String[] args) { //main method
    int a= getContactsCount(); //calling the method
    System.out.println(a);  //displaying the integer
}
}
```

Comment: BTW since there is an android tag on this as well I would like to remind you that you are able to use Log.d(a) instead of System.out.println(a) in android. This answer is purely written in JAVA.

Comment: From additional questions in http://stackoverflow.com/a/26572632/2626313 it seems that OP wants to know how to display the number on the screen of Android application (sort of Android Studio hello world tutorial). Can you add something similar (or reference to something similar) to your answer?

Comment: @xmojmr I would recommend the OP to follow this and build a [Simple User Interface](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html) :)

Answer (score 0):

To display the value in a textview:

```
public class MyActvitiy Extends Activity{
    public void onCreate(Bundle b){
    super.onCreate(b);
    //sets the view to the xml file that contains the textview
    setContentView(R.layout.myActvityLayout);
    //inflates textview from xml
    TextView tv_contactCount = findViewById(R.id.tv_contactCount);
    //creates a new example object
    Example e = new Example();
    //sets the textview to equal the count
    tv_contactCount.setText(e.getContactsCount());
    }
}
```

However, you may want to go over [Android fundamentals](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html) to ensure you get a comprehensive understanding.