# Android Studio, Sql, TextView

Tags: android, sql, textview

I am posting following my [first answered post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26568702/android-studio-getcount).

After testing and adding the advised modifications, I still cannot get my code to work. Each time I start over the tuto, then try to add my code, then it fails.

If you could correct me or point me where I missed the point, it would be great.

This works fine:

In MyActivity.java There is a clickable button

```
/** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
public void goExample(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Example.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Which brings the class Example:

```
 public class Example extends Activity {

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            TextView total = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.total);
            setContentView(R.layout.example);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
            return true;
        }}
```

Along with its view example.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Example">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+android:id/total"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

No problem until I try to add my code (as follows):

```
public class Example extends MyActivity {

    private TaskDBHelper helper;

    public int getContactsCount() {
        helper = new TaskDBHelper(Example.this);
        SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getReadableDatabase();
        String countQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + Playas.TABLE;
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        return cursor.getCount();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Example example = new Example();
        int a = example.getContactsCount();
        System.out.println(a);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        TextView total = (TextView )findViewById(R.id.total);
        total.setText(String.valueOf(getContactsCount()));
        setContentView(R.layout.example);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then it miserably fails, with the following errors:

```
6715-6715/tab.sqltesting.com.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{tab.sqltesting.com.myapplication/tab.sqltesting.com.myapplication.Example}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteQuery: SELECT * FROM joueurs
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2122)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
...
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteQuery: SELECT * FROM joueurs
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteClosable.acquireReference(SQLiteClosable.java:55)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.fillWindow(SQLiteQuery.java:58)
```

Honestly, I do not know what to do, and any help would be greatly appreciated...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your class example. you should declare widgets after setcontentview();

```
public class Example extends Activity {

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.example);
            TextView total = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.total);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
            return true;
        }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you reverse tour 2 lines of code.

instead of this:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        TextView total = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.total);
        setContentView(R.layout.example);
    }
```

Do it like this:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.example);
        TextView total = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.total);
    }
```

**HINT**: You should first set your content view, and then declare variables.